# A Bash script to set up Github projects

Tags: bash

I am using Nitrous.io for some basic dev, the code is managed with git.
I would like to use a script to set up the git projects on my dev machines (several between Nitrous, work and home).
[Edit:  Git repo has two rails projects underneath, could have more]

I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
current=${1-`pwd`}
echo "Starting directory is $current"
cd $current
read -p "Press [Enter] key to start install..."

git init
git remote add nitrous https://github.com/[user]/[project].git
git pull nitrous master

for dir in "$( find $current -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[!.]*' )";
  do
    echo "Setting up $dir"
    #cd $dir
    #bundle install
    #rake db:migrate
  done

  cd $current
  exit 0
```

But it fails to change directories. (I have commented out the rails actions for the moment)

```
action@testlog-xxxx:~/workspace$ ../setup.sh                                                                                                                                         
Starting directory is /home/action/workspace                                                                                                                                          
Press [Enter] key to start install...                                                                                                                                                 
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/action/workspace/.git/                                                                                                                      
remote: Counting objects: 175, done.                                                                                                                                                  
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (128/128), done.                                                                                                                                    
remote: Total 175 (delta 31), reused 175 (delta 31)                                                                                                                                   
Receiving objects: 100% (175/175), 29.44 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.                                                                                                                       
Resolving deltas: 100% (31/31), done.                                                                                                                                                 
From https://github.com/[user]/[project]                                                                                                                                               
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD                                                                                                                                         
 * [new branch]      master     -> nitrous/master                                                                                                                                     
Setting up /home/action/workspace/testlog                                                                                                                                             
/home/action/workspace/testembedded
```

Anyone with a clue to why?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`cd` in a shell script cd's the shell that runs the script, not your interactive shell.

You can't do what you want unless you execute with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT, This worked for me:

```
res="$( find $current -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[!.]*' )" 
for dir in $res
 do
     echo "$dir"
     ls -la     
 done
```

Comment: Hey Michael,the bundle and rake commands are not in the subdirectories.  Rake does allow me to specify the RakeFile as a parameter, so I can call that one from the higher level directory with "rake -f testlog/Rakefile db:migrate", however the bundle call doesn't have that option.

Comment: see edit above. if you  for dir in "$( find $current -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[!.]*' )";
  do
    echo "Setting up $dir"      $dir will have all available dirs in the first iteration. you can't cd into that ...